# Knowing when an external process' window shows

Tags: c#, .net, process, window

How can I get an event relative to when the main window of an external process is showed?

I start the process using

```
pi = new ProcessStartInfo();
[...]
Process.Start(pi)
```

Than I want to get the moment the main window appears and resize and move it using:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like this:

```
async void RepositionWindow(Process process)
        {
            while ((int)process.MainWindowHandle == 0)
            {
                await Task.Delay(100);
            }
            IntPtr hWnd = process.MainWindowHandle;
            while (!IsWindowVisible(hWnd))
            {
                await Task.Delay(100);
            }
            MoveWindow(hWnd, 0, 0, 500, 800, true);
        }

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Probably not the best solution, but a good starting point